# Autocomplete Jquery Json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm trying to use an external Json as source for the autocomplete Jquery UI plugin : http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

This code works fine:

```
    var availableTags = ["aberdeen","aberystwyth","aberystwyth juniors"]

    $( "#enter-your-parkrun" ).autocomplete({
    open: function(e) {
      var results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(availableTags, e.term);
            response(results);
       valid = false;
     },
     select: function(e){
        valid = true;
     },
     close: function(e){
        if (!valid) $(this).val('');
     },
     source: availableTags,

});

$("#enter-your-parkrun").change(function(){
    if (availableTags.indexOf($(this).val()) == -1){
        $(this).val("");
    }
});
```

but as I have almost 800 values, I need to use an external source. I've tried different things but I can't find a way to make  it work:

```
$( "#enter-your-parkrun" ).autocomplete({

     source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax({
          url: "http://tribesports.com/pages/parkrun-event-list",
          dataType: "jsonp",
          data: {
            q: request.term
          },
          success: function( data ) {
            response( data );
          }
        });
      },
     minLength: 2,
     delay: 400,

});
```

I'm not sure what q: request.term should be and if data should be parsed? I also need to add validation to make sure that only the values in the list can be accepted, it works on my first example, not too sure how to transfer this to my second code.

Thanks

Comment: That server doesn't support JSONP is the problem.

Comment: Are you getting the response from external source..? How does it look like..? *"I also need to add validation to make sure that only the values in the list can be accepted"* - what list..? `availableTags`..? If you only accept those why are you sending an external request..? If not, how do you relate the data in `availableTags` with the response from external source..?

Answer (score 0):

`request.term` is what the user has typed so far, and should be passed to the server as a parameter in the AJAX call so that the server can filter the results.

In the [.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) call, `dataType` is the kind of data you're expecting back from the server. You have not shown it, but most probably is `json`, not `jsonp`. If it's JSON jQuery parses it automatically.

As to sending the term to the server,

- if you use the GET method (which is the default), you have to include it in the query string, like this:

  ```
  url: 'http://tribesports.com/pages/parkrun-event-list?term='+request.term
  ```
- if you use other method (usually POST) you have to specify the method option in the jquery ajax call options, and also specify the contentType, which shuld be JSON:  contentType: "application/json", and send the data in the requiredn format

As you can see this all depends on what's on the server.